# Pandas pivot_table create a new column for each entry

Tags: pandas, stack, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe like this

[image]

and I would like to transform it into the following (without using any loop!):

[image]

Any ideas how to do that??

In case the images don't show:

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: Name and Hobbys. And I have the following lines:

```
Anna drawing
Anna swimming
Anna skiing
Lisa running
Lisa singing
Tom drawing
```

And I want to transform it into a dataframe with 4 columns: Name, Hobby 1, Hobby 2, Hobby 3. And to have the following lines:

```
Anna drawing swimming skiing
Lisa running singing NaN
Tom drawing NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gruopby` and `reset_index` to create numeric index for each hobby in each name group. Reshape (unstack) to obtain matrix format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anna','Anna','Anna','Lisa','Lisa','Tom' ],
                  'Hobby':['drawing','swimming','skiing','running','singing','drawing']})

result = (df.groupby('Name')['Hobby']
            .apply(lambda x:x.reset_index(drop=True))
            .unstack()
            .rename(columns=lambda x:f'Hobby {x+1}'))
```

Edit: Combination of two hobbies

```
df_merge = (df.merge(df, on='Name')
              .assign(Hobby_combi=lambda x:x.Hobby_x+'|'+x.Hobby_y)
              .loc[lambda x:x.Hobby_x!=x.Hobby_y]
              .groupby(['Name','Hobby_combi'])
              .size()
              .unstack()
              .reindex(df['Name'].unique())
              .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

df_merge.sum()
```

Comment: Hey Mark, 
thank you so much, that's awesome!!! Works perfectly. Only in the very last line I changed it to ...rename(columns=lambda x:'Hobby'+str(x+1))

Comment: @MariaReinhardt No worries. The last bit is the so called f-string, which should be available from python 3.6 onwards. The change you made is absolutely fine.

Comment: And do you by any chance also have an idea how I could now count the occurences of combinations of 2 hobbies? I mean in this case, there's no combination of two hobbies appearing more than once, but imagine that Tom has a value in "Hobby 2" and it's skiing. So the combination "drawing" & "skiing" occurs twice. I need a list of the most common combinations of 2 hobbies and how often they occur...

Comment: @MariaReinhardt It's doable in pandas, but significantly more difficult. I recommend you carefully prepare a minimal example with expected output before posting a new question.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks again. Unfortunately I get the error " 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Hobby_x' "

Comment: @MariaReinhardt The pandas you are running is likely to be an old version. This definitely works for 0.25. For older version, can you modify the first line into `df.merge(df, on='Name', suffixes=('_x', '_y'))`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get it to work, but thank you for your help anyway!!